# Max Stress on Weld

Tags: structural-engineering, mechanical

Part is welded to a plate, based on the below free body diagram how would I determine the max stress in the weld? It seems half the weld is in tension and the other half is in compression.

[image: free body diagram]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sum Loads About Centroid of the Welds**

[image]

**Max. Weld Stresses:**

$f_{c,t} = \dfrac{P}{A} \pm \dfrac{M}{S}$ (lbs/in, along each weld length)

**Alternative:**

If the above weld pattern does not produce enough strength, before increasing the weld size, try to switch the welds to other sides as shown below. Other than the increase in section modulus, everything remains the same.

[image]

**Note: The square tubing usually has round corners, which will result in a shorter effective weld length.**

[image]